# Definition of $a_{0}$ - what is wrong with my calculations?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, harmonic-analysis

Consider the following problem, which was extracted from page 13 of [these lecture notes](https://www.fuw.edu.pl/%7Emarcnap/maths_BEC_notes.pdf). Consider $w$ to be radially symmetric ($w(x) = w(|x|)$), compactly supported and nonnegative. Let $f$ be radially symmetric solution of:
$$(-\Delta + \frac{1}{2}w)f = 0$$
with $\lim_{|x| \to \infty}f(x) = 1$. When $x$ is really large, we have $f(x) = C-\frac{a_{0}}{|x|}$, and since $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}f(x) = 1$, this implies $f(x) = 1 - \frac{a_{0}}{|x|}$. So far, so good.

However, the problem now is to prove that $a_{0}$ is also given by:
$$8\pi a_{0} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}dx w(x)f(x).$$
My reasoning is the following. Because $f$ solves the above equation, we have (passing to spherical coordinates):
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}dx w(x)f(x) = 2\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}dx \Delta f = 8\pi \int_{0}^{\infty}dr r^{2}\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{d}{dr}\bigg{(}r^{2}\frac{df}{dr}\bigg{)} = r^{2}\frac{df}{dr}\bigg{|}_{0}^{\infty}$$
I know that $\lim_{r\to \infty}r^{2}\frac{df}{dr} = a_{0}$, but how to ensure that $\lim_{r\to 0}r^{2}\frac{df}{dr} = 0$? I have no further hypothesis on $f$ and it seems not possible to conclude this. Any help is welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because $w$ is compactly supported, thus far away the solution looks like  that ($\Delta f = 0$ for $|x|>R$). Near the origin $\frac{df}{dr}$ should be bounded (because $f\in C^2$ near the origin), and thus that zero limit when $r\to 0^+$.

---

Edit based on the feedback in comments: if $f\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$, which implies $\displaystyle \int_D|\nabla f|^2$ must be finite for a domain including the origin, the most singular function to satisfy the integrability is $f\sim 1/|x|^{1/2-\epsilon} = 1/|r|^{1/2-\epsilon}$ near the origin for an arbitrary small $\epsilon>0$. This will make the limit zero as well.

Comment: Shuhao, many thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for! Could you please elaborate a bit more about the second claim? Why is $f \in C^{2}$ near the origin and why this implies $df/dr$ to be bounded?

Comment: Oops, I mean of course it is $C^{2}$. But why this implies $df/dr$ is bounded still tricks me.

Comment: For instance: $1/x$ is $C^{2}$ on $(0,+\infty)$ and it is not bounded near the origin.

Comment: @Idontgetit I don't know if we are talking about the same $C^k$ space. For $\mathbb{R}^3$, even if we talk about Sobolev spaces, $1/|x|$ is not in $W^{2, p}$ for any $p\geq 1$. If we talk about the solution in the classical sense, $f$ should be at least $C^2$ near the origin, which means $\partial^2 f/\partial r^2$ is continuous in a compact set near the origin, thus exclude cases like $1/|x|$.

Comment: My differential equation holds in the sense of distributions, so $f\in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. But how does continuity of second derivative and boundedness near origin imply the existence of the limit?

Comment: I see. If that is the case, I just made an edit to my answer please check.